# Cannot get python packages to work

Tags: python, import, package, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to calculate levenshtein distance between 2 strings. Tried to install 2 packages (python-levenshtein) and pylev

Used ananconda (on Win 64 machine) for the install

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/trent pylevenshtein
```

It looks like the package got installed

```
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: ..............
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda2:

The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
pylevenshtein-0.10.1       |           py27_0          34 KB
setuptools-20.1.1          |           py27_0         674 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         707 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

pylevenshtein: 0.10.1-py27_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

setuptools:    19.6.2-py27_0 --> 20.1.1-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
pylevenshtein- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:0042.36    kB/s
setuptools-20. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02 320.43 kB/s
 Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
```

However , when I try to import the package it says no module name pylev . Same thing happens with Python-levenshtein . Command used are (tried variants of his but doesn't seem to work)

```
import pylev
import Levenshtein
```

Unable to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Are you sure your python path is properly configured as an environment variable on your system and isn't in conflict with another installation of python?

Comment: I had installed "Seaborn" package the same way and it worked.

Comment: Dont know if this helps but I can see the packages in this folder - C:\Anaconda2\pkgs  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some modules (this is a C extension) must be compiled for the architecture you are using. See explained for your case [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/tJAUKyBVEAM).

But you can always use compiled versions if they are available (as is the case for pylevenshtein) from [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)